# How to call AGI with Asterisk parameters within Queue

Tags: queue, asterisk, agi

I'm trying to get into an agi by passing the parameters through the Queue command:

```
$agi->exec("Queue comercial,,,,,envia_dados.agi[${numero},${id_chamada}]");
```

What in extensions would be:

```
exten=>200,n,Queue(comercial,,,,,"envia_dados.agi,${numero},${id_chamada}")
```

But I do not know how to send these parameters to AGI from Queue, always from error, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should just send params as next param to queue call.

i.e you have remove any quotes

You also CAN'T use variables when you use AGI call(variables will not be substituted).

You have use get_variable and put substitute yourself.